# Assigning role is not inserting to its corresponding model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am implementing Assigning roles to a user. I have implemented this using has many through association. the requirement says there can be any number of roles to a particular user. have created User, Role model and linked this two with a userrole model. when I assign roles to a particular user, it is not saving in my userrole table. and my code is ass follows 
//index.html.erb of user model

I am calling assign role page with the following code of index.html.erb which is of the User model, I am getting user id in the URL of new.html.erb of userrole model so not getting the user id is not my issue.

```
<pre>
<%= link_to t('.assign_role', default: t("helpers.links.assign")),
                  new_user_role_path(user_id: user.id,user_name: user.first_name),
                 method: :get,
                 class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
</pre>
```

//new.html.erb

```
<h1>Assign Roles to <%=params[:user_name ]%></h1>
<%= form_for @user_role, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal user" } do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Assign_Role_1, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
        <div class="col-lg-10" >
            <%= f.select(:role_id, Role.all.map{|e| [e.name, e.id]},{ :include_blank => "Please select" }, { class: 'form-control' } ) %>
        </div>
        <%=f.error_span(:Assign_Role) %>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
        <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                  users_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
      </div>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

//controller

```
   class UserRolesController < ApplicationController   

    def index
    @user_role = UserRole.all   
    end

    def new
    @user_role = UserRole.new   
    end

     def create  
      @user_role = UserRole.new(user_role_params)
        if UserRole.exists?(user_id: user_role_params[:user_id]) 
              flash[:error] = "User already exists."
              redirect_to '/' and return
        end
        if @user_role.save
              flash[:success] = "New UserRole created."
              redirect_to @user_role
        else
              render 'new'
        end
     end

     def edit   
     end

     def destroy  
     end

     def show
       @user_role = UserRole.all   
     end


  private  
     def user_role_params
        params.require(:user_role).permit( :role_id,:user_id
                                 )   
     end
```

end

my table

```
create_table "user_roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "role_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["role_id"], name: "index_user_roles_on_role_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_roles_on_user_id"
  end
```

since I am a baby in ruby and newborn to rails, please guide me even if its silly error.

Comment: Hi, what happens when you submit the form? Do you see an error on screen? Do you see any output in the server logs?

Comment: no, actually it will go redirect to new.html.erb. if's else part is getting executed

Comment: @sushmithabhaskar  Is it user form or separate form for role only ?

Comment: Based on your comment, it seems that your role is not saving to the database, and I'm guessing it's because you are not associating a `user_id` with it.

Comment: no, its neither user form nor role form. it is the userrole form I am implementing it with has many through association. I have created a separate controller for userrole so its new.html.erb is  form of userrole model

Comment: @stephenmurdoch  i am getting userid. on top of my form you can find <h1>Assign Roles to <%=params[:user_name ]%></h1> even in url i am getting user name and id

Comment: @sushmithabhaskar that's probably not the `user_id`, it's the `user_name`, and it's not actually being associated with the user_role. I will post an answer with suggested code.

Comment: ok I will test with your code

Comment: @sushmithabhaskar check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting user_id in your form try below codes in your form

```
<h1>Assign Roles to <%=params[:user_name ]%></h1>
<%= form_for @user_role, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal user" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user_id %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Assign_Role_1, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
        <div class="col-lg-10" >
            <%= f.select(:role_id, Role.all.map{|e| [e.name, e.id]},{ :include_blank => "Please select" }, { class: 'form-control' } ) %>
        </div>
        <%=f.error_span(:Assign_Role) %>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
        <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                  users_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
      </div>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

In your controller

```
def new
  @user_id = params[:user_id]
  @user_role = UserRole.new   
end

def create  
  @user_role = UserRole.new(user_role_params)
    if UserRole.exists?(user_id: user_role_params[:user_id]) 
          flash[:error] = "User already exists."
          redirect_to '/' and return
    end
    if @user_role.save
          flash[:success] = "New UserRole created."
          redirect_to @user_role
    else
          render 'new'
    end
end

private  
 def user_role_params
    params.require(:user_role).permit( :role_id,:user_id
                             )   
 end
```

Instead of checking role add validation in your user role  model  as below

```
  validates :role_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
```

Or if possible don't show roles in select box which are already present for that user

Comment: thank you. can you please explain me, @user_id = params[:user_id].   that is the only line I put from your code and it worked

Comment: @sushmithabhaskar you are passing parameter to action of controller but if you want to use it in view you need to store it in instance variable. like @user_id = params[:user_id] . you can use instance variable which define as `@variable ` in view of that action

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I don't think you are passing the user_id to the controller. Try something like the following:

```
def new
  # Get the user somehow
  user = User.find_by(name: params[:user_name])
  # associate the new role with the user
  @user_role = user.user_roles.new   
end

def create
  # Get the user somehow
  user = User.find_by(name: params[:user_name])

  # associate the new role with the user
  @user_role = user.user_roles.new(user_role_params)

  if @user_role.save
    flash[:success] = "New UserRole created."
    redirect_to @user_role
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

You might need to experiment with this as your setup is slightly unusual. But you will get there :). Good luck.